# awk- remove lines if two columns equal

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

Apologies if this is very obvious- I'm a bash beginner!  I would like to remove lines from a file if the 1st column equals the 3rd, and if the 2nd equals the 4th.  The structure of this file (file_A) is:

```
chr1    25000   chr2    16475000    1
chr1    25000   chr2    114325000   1
chr1    25000   chr2    224825000   1
chr1    25000   chr3    196825000   1
```

To see if I could get lines that satisfy the condition, I ran:

```
awk '$1==$3 && $2==$4' file_A > test_equal
```

test_equal contains 54640 lines.

But then when I tried to do everything in one line, i.e.

```
 awk '$1!=$3 && $2!=$4' file_A > test_unequal
```

test_unequal contains 12767257 lines, while file_A originally had 24384120 lines. Shouldn't there be 24384120-54640 = 24329480 lines in test_unequal?

I'm sure this is a silly mistake on my part, but I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: `!($1==$3 && $2==$4)` is same as `$1!=$3 || $2!=$4`... see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: Sundeep, thanks for your response.  I'm still confused- how can I make my command work correctly?  I tried various combinations of parentheses but they still yield the same result.

Comment: can you create a sample file, say 5-6 lines with some lines matching `$1==$3 && $2==$4`? your current sample doesn't... then see results for `awk '$1==$3 && $2==$4' sample` and `awk '!($1==$3 && $2==$4)' sample`

Comment: Ah, got it- was easier to see with a small sample.  Thanks Sundeep.